# How to I access the first LINQ element?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

After I execute this code:

```
Dim arr = From ctl In ContainerCtl.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
            Select ctl
            Where (ctl.Enabled = True) AndAlso _
            (Not TypeOf ctl Is Label) AndAlso _
            (Not TypeOf ctl Is Panel) AndAlso _
            (Not TypeOf ctl Is GroupBox) AndAlso _
            (Not TypeOf ctl Is C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid AndAlso bSkipGrid)
            Order By ctl.TabIndex
```

How do I access the first element? I need to access it as a Control object.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Using First() or FirstOrDefault() never works:

[image: Error screen...]

Comment: Do you have `Imports System.Linq` in your class file?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to include the following at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then all you will need to do is use the following:

```
arr.First()
```

Or if you may have zero results in your enumerable (which would cause the above to throw an exception).

```
arr.FirstOrDefault()
```

Make sure in the later case you check for `null`, note that the later also has the problem of not saying when the first object is `null`, but that is a question for another day.

Comment: It works if you include the right namespace. `System.Linq` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about vb but in c# there is a arr.First() method that will return first element of collection or you can alwasy do arr.ToArray()[0] or arr.ToList()[0]

Answer (score 0):

Is your statement ordering wrong?  shouldn't it be:

```
Dim arr = From ctl In ContainerCtl.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
        Where (ctl.Enabled = True) AndAlso _
        (Not TypeOf ctl Is Label) AndAlso _
        (Not TypeOf ctl Is Panel) AndAlso _
        (Not TypeOf ctl Is GroupBox) AndAlso _
        (Not TypeOf ctl Is C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid AndAlso bSkipGrid)
        Order By ctl.TabIndex
        Select ctl
```

Then just call

```
arr.First()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've decided to simply use a For Each Loop and grab the first valid element. I never figured out why First() never worked. I used all the techniques mentioned and no luck.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have `Option Infer Off`. Open the project properties and set `Option Infer On` or add `Option Infer On` to the top of the code file.